# Removing the padding between inline elements

Tags: css, html, space

I have two span tags that contain content.  The first span tag will hold content from the client and the second acts like a "blipping-cursor" (I'm using JavaScript to turn its "display" style from inline to none every 500 milliseconds).  Currently, everything works great except for the fact that there is a bit of spacing (just a bit in IE and a TON (one or two spaces worth) in Webkit (nested parenthesis for the win!))) between the content in the first span and the second span.

So my question is simple (well, the question, the answer may or may not be easy), how do I remove this space currently occupying the spot between span one and span two?

Here is a jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/DalexL/6pZB3/

As you can see, there is a highlightable single-space in between the two spans content.

Thanks if you can!

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? If possible, strip it down to the bare minimum required to replicate the issue, and put it on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing any code, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you have a line break in between the two spans:

```
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

That will cause a space sometimes. If you get rid of it, the space should go away:

```
<span></span><span></span>
```

Comment: You picked a good tree because it worked!  Wow, I never even though of that!  I'll go find a desk to "headdesk" now.  I DEEM THIS QUESTION, ANSWERED!

Comment: Confirmed, the line-break does have an effect on the spacing.