# Remove inline padding without removing line breaks

Tags: html, css, sass, haml

I've got a collection of `span`s which I want to squeeze into one line, very similar to the Language Stats graph on a Github Project Page. The problem is that the `span`s have spacing between them (which I didn't add) and so with the parent at `width: 100%;`, the line wraps.

#### Github:

[image: Github Language Stats]

#### My attempt:

[image: My attempt]

I found some helpful information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995930/removing-the-padding-between-inline-elements) asked earlier on SO. It showed me a solution to the problem I was having.

However, I still have a problem - because I'm using HAML, I've got line breaks between the spans in my original source, and I don't know how to remove them. I'm looking for a way to remove the spacing between spans when the spans *do* have line breaks between them.

I've got a Fiddle showing what I'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/j9Y7a/1/ -- the above version shows how I want it to look, the bottom shows what happens when the line breaks are present.

*How can I remove the spacing between line-separated `span` tags **without** removing the line breaks?*

Comment: You could always resort to `font-size:0`.. that would work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859 .. updated example - http://jsfiddle.net/29YVA/

Comment: In Haml you can control the [whitespace around tags with `<` and `>`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_).

Comment: Thanks, @matt! I debated also asking for the HAML solution. Good to know there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
float:left;
```

to `.pipeline-bucket-segment`, then all segments are put nicely together.

Read all about floats [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).